# Linux Machines and DHCP reservation

Tags: cisco, dhcp, fedora

Why do Linux machine DHCP bindings show a different MAC address to ifconfig on that same machine. This is the second Linux machine where I have struggled to create a DHCP reservation because of inconsistent MAC addresses.

### FEDORA

```
[admin@prism ~]$ ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.190.0.150  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.190.0.255
        inet6 fe80::fae1:6ad1:dc40:cf1e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 44:8a:5b:b5:35:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

### CISCO 871 ROUTER

```
HAMS-WAN-RTR-871#sh ip dhcp bind | i 10.190

10.190.0.150        ff5b.b535.e200.0430.    Aug 26 2019 06:31 PM    Automatic

10.190.0.151        0100.2268.195f.bf       Aug 26 2019 03:24 PM    Automatic
```

Comment: can you please give us Fedora version and what you are using as ```dhcp``` client ? Are you using ```systemd-networkd``` ?

Comment: It looks like it's not using the mac address directly to identify the host. It is using part of it (5b:b5:35:e2), however. What do you get when you do `nmcli -g ipv4.dhcp-client-id connection show <connection_name>` on the client? Use `nmcli connection show` to list connection names.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get the client using the command but had no luck. Please see below;[root@prism admin]# nmcli -g ipv4.dhcp-client-id connection show
Error: invalid field 'ipv4.dhcp-client-id'; allowed fields: NAME,UUID,TYPE,TIMESTAMP,TIMESTAMP-REAL,AUTOCONNECT,AUTOCONNECT-PRIORITY,READONLY,DBUS-PATH,ACTIVE,DEVICE,STATE,ACTIVE-PATH,SLAVE,FILENAME.

Answer (score 0):

Share the connection output

To show the active connection use #nmcli connection show --active and then check with the ip4 dhcp client ID

Note: Remember to use tab completion when in doubt.

Comment: [root@prism admin]# nmcli connection show --active
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
eno1  739a7739-ae19-3427-beb5-35420ede696a  ethernet  eno1

Comment: [root@prism admin]# nmcli connection show
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
eno1  739a7739-ae19-3427-beb5-35420ede696a  ethernet  eno1   
[root@prism admin]# nmcli connection show eno1 | grep 739
connection.uuid:                        739a7739-ae19-3427-beb5-35420ede696a
GENERAL.UUID:                           739a7739-ae19-3427-beb5-35420ede696a
[root@prism admin]#

Comment: Thanks, sorry I think I am getting there slowly.